# How can i bring my bitcoins back to me?

Tags: sending

I deposited bitcoins on an online investment. the record on my bitcoin wallet shows that it was indeed sent to the wallet address of the online investment. but my account on that online investment is still empty or zero. they didn't put my bitcoins on my account to that investment. what should I do. I want my bitcoins bring back to me. please help me.

Comment: I would suggest researching Ponzi schemes. If it is a ponzi scheme, your best bet is getting enough of your friends to join so that their money funds your returns.

Comment: I would suggest to disregard the above advice, because it is likely to add losing friends to your predicament of losing money.

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin transactions are not reversable. The only way for you to get your bitcoins returned is by convincing your business partner to send them back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Only whoever you sent your bitcoins to can help you. If they are scammers you're out of luck.